# Is it possible to get an HTML attribute to CSS?

Tags: html, css, attributes

I'm making a carousel and I wanna set a background image for every carousel item and I want the background image to be the same image that's inside the item, so the image has a `src` attribute and I want to get it into the CSS automatically to set it as a background

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: This is not possible. You mean something like background-image: url( #MyImage[src]) but this is not valid css

Comment: Its possible if you are using php java or any server side language

Comment: @AmmarCSE I didn't mean a specific way to do it, thanks anyway.

Comment: @prashantthakre Wow, I'm already newbie...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with **Javascript**

Suppose, you have an `<img>` like

```
<img id="my_img" src="my_img_src"/>
```

Then, you can get the src of the `<img>` as follows

```
var myimgsrc = document.getElementById("my_img").src;
```

Now, the variable `myimgsrc` holds the src of your `<img>`.

Again using Javascript you can use the variable to set the CSS like,

```
document.getElementById("my_img").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+myimgsrc+"')";
```

Try this..